# Angular ng-click function populates table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

So I have these boxes that show minimal info for an array created using an ng-repeat. There could be 1 and 10 items returned with objects and their properties These boxes are clickable and when clicked, should populate the table. Problem is, I keep getting a reference error and for the likes of me, cannot see why. The function is defined and should call and fill the table based on the Id of the box to fill the table with more info. The array object is called "swipe".

My html for the the boxes:

```
<div  class="swipeBoxes" ng-repeat="swipe in swipes">
    <a href="" ng-click="editSwipe(swipe.id)" >
        <div class="swipeBox col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimLine" style="width: 3px; position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px;">{{ $index + 1 }}.</span>
                <span class="claimedLeft">swipe date:</span>
                <span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimedLeft">provider:</span
                ><span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.merchant }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimedLeft">amount:</span>
                <span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.amount | currency }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

My target table that should be filled with data once one of the objects are selected from above:

```
<div class="swipeDetails col-md-12">
    <div class="swipeFlexHead col-md-12">
        <p>Swipe Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swipeFlexHead2 col-md-12">
        <p>{{ swipe.merchant }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="swipeFlexElement col-md-4">
            <p>Swipe Date</p>
            <p>{{ swipe.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swipeFlexElement col-md-4">
            <p>Status</p>
            <p>{{ swipe.status }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swipeFlexElement col-md-4">
            <p>Card Used</p>
            <p>{{ swipe.cardHolder }} {{ swipe.cardUsed }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-12">                                            
        <div class="swipeFlexElement col-md-4">
            <p>Swipe Amount</p>
            <p>{{ swipe.amount | currency }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swipeFlexElement col-md-4">
            <p>Amount Requiring Documentation</p>
            <p>{{ swipe.reqAmount | currency }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swipeFlexElement col-md-4">
            <p>Documentation Due Date</p>
            <p>{{ swipe.dueDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</p>
        </div>                                                                                                                        
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, my controller for this that is pulling data and has the 'editSwipe' function:

```
app.controller('swipeController', ['$scope', 'swipesService', '$location', 'Upload', '$timeout', '$filter', 'utilsService',
  function ($scope, swipesService, $location, Upload, $timeout, $filter, utilsService) {

    $scope.swipes = [];
    $scope.swipeFormSubmitted = false;

    swipesService.getSwipes().then(function (results) {

        $scope.swipes = results.data;

    }); 

    $scope.swipe = {
        id: '',
        descr: '',
        merchant: '',
        date: '',
        amount: '',
        reqAmount: '',
        status: '',
        cardUsed: '',
        cardHolder: '',
        dueDate: ''
    }

    $scope.editSwipe = function(id) {
        $scope.swipeInfo = angular.copy(swipe);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: So what's the reference error? The swipe var?

Comment: Yes, says "ReferenceError: swipe is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `editSwipe` function you are not doing anything with `id`. With `angular.copy(swipe)` you are using swipe which is not defined. I guess you want to copy the swipe you've clicked, then you need to do

```
ng-click="editSwipe(swipe)"
```

```
$scope.editSwipe = function(swipe) {
    $scope.swipe = angular.copy(swipe); // I don't see where you use swipeInfo?
};
```

BTW: is there any need to deep copy the swipe? Can't you just pass the reference `$scope.swipe = swipe;`

Comment: Thanks! Was getting mixed between swipe, swipes, and swipeInfo.